# Get data from Data reader terminal to GUI (QtCreator)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface, data-distribution-service

I need a small GUI showing the data from the data reader below. Say I have 10 messages displayed by the data reader in the console, all I need is in the GUI it has to display 1st message for half a second and the second so on....in the Textbrowser of QtCreator.

Any Help Appreciated.

```
DDS_DomainParticipant_get_current_time (participant, &ts1);

status = Chat_ChatMessageDataReader_take(
    chatAdmin,
    msgSeq,
    infoSeq,
    DDS_LENGTH_UNLIMITED,
    DDS_ANY_SAMPLE_STATE,
    DDS_ANY_VIEW_STATE,
    DDS_ALIVE_INSTANCE_STATE );

checkStatus(status, "Chat_NamedMessageDataReader_take");

for (i = 0; i < msgSeq->_length; i++) 
{
    DDS_DomainParticipant_get_current_time (participant, &ts2);
    Chat_ChatMessage *msg = &(msgSeq->_buffer[i]);
    printf ("%d: %s t1.secs %d t1.ns %u t2.secs %d t2.ns %u \n", msg->userID, msg->content, ts1.sec, ts1.nanosec,ts2.sec, ts2.nanosec);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Output:
      MessageBoard has opened: send a ChatMessage with userID = -1 to close it....

```
    1: Hi there, I will send you 20 more messages. t1.secs 1465476565 t1.ns 676311347 t2.secs 1465476565 t2.ns 676395551 
    1: 1 t1.secs 1465476566 t1.ns 676569175 t2.secs 1465476566 t2.ns 676596400 
    1: 2 t1.secs 1465476567 t1.ns 677616392 t2.secs 1465476567 t2.ns 677648204 
    1: 3 t1.secs 1465476568 t1.ns 678910684 t2.secs 1465476568 t2.ns 678940815 
    1: 4 t1.secs 1465476569 t1.ns 680225024 t2.secs 1465476569 t2.ns 680255376 
    1: 5 t1.secs 1465476570 t1.ns 681507684 t2.secs 1465476570 t2.ns 681534887 
    1: 6 t1.secs 1465476571 t1.ns 682657681 t2.secs 1465476571 t2.ns 682689735 
    1: 7 t1.secs 1465476572 t1.ns 683901346 t2.secs 1465476572 t2.ns 683931532 
    1: 8 t1.secs 1465476573 t1.ns 684895076 t2.secs 1465476573 t2.ns 684926328 
    1: 9 t1.secs 1465476574 t1.ns 686201827 t2.secs 1465476574 t2.ns 686231445 
    1: 10 t1.secs 1465476575 t1.ns 687286401 t2.secs 1465476575 t2.ns 687318820 
    1: 11 t1.secs 1465476576 t1.ns 687569194 t2.secs 1465476576 t2.ns 687602357 
    1: 12 t1.secs 1465476577 t1.ns 688870441 t2.secs 1465476577 t2.ns 688900707 
    1: 13 t1.secs 1465476578 t1.ns 690184430 t2.secs 1465476578 t2.ns 690213984 
    1: 14 t1.secs 1465476579 t1.ns 691483124 t2.secs 1465476579 t2.ns 691517976 
    1: 15 t1.secs 1465476580 t1.ns 692274389 t2.secs 1465476580 t2.ns 692299778 
    1: 16 t1.secs 1465476581 t1.ns 693601908 t2.secs 1465476581 t2.ns 693667232 
    1: 17 t1.secs 1465476582 t1.ns 694371847 t2.secs 1465476582 t2.ns 694395932 
    1: 18 t1.secs 1465476583 t1.ns 695229750 t2.secs 1465476583 t2.ns 695421352 
    1: 19 t1.secs 1465476584 t1.ns 696229812 t2.secs 1465476584 t2.ns 696261942 
    1: 20 t1.secs 1465476585 t1.ns 696390252 t2.secs 1465476585 t2.ns 696417861
```

I tried Accessing the data from a text file, which is actually not real time any more. I want now to access the data in real-time (i.e. directly form the terminal to GUI).

From a text file:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFile file("/home/akhil/test.txt");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        QMessageBox::information(0,"info",file.errorString());

    QTextStream in(&file);
    ui->textBrowser->setText(in.readAll());

}
```

Comment: I am not very clear on your requirement. Do you really need a GUI? you mention the text browser in qtcreator, are you talking about the output console (stdout)?  otherwise I assume you just want to print out each message with a 0.5 second delay between them (i.e. you can use 'QThread::msleep(500);' as a crude fix or you can use a QTimer (better solution)... can you clarify what you want a little for me?, thanks

Comment: @code_fodder i mean User interface in QtCreator has widgets in that we have this textbrowser. so i want to display this data reader output (which i get in the console of linux) to this qtcreator textbrowser widget. I have never done a GUI using Qt before, excuse me if my explanation is not so clear

Comment: ah ok, got it - using QTextBrowser!

Answer (score 0):

**A Crude Way**

Ok here is a very crude way to do what you want - useful for a quick test:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFile file("/home/akhil/test.txt");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        QMessageBox::information(0,"info",file.errorString());

    QTextStream in(&file);
    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
        ui->textBrowser->setText(in.readLine()); // read one line and display it
        QThread::msleep(500); // Pause for 500ms: #include <QThread>
    }
}
```

**The Proper Way**

However a better method would be to open the QTextStream as a member object then you can use QTimer:

create the timer and connect it:

```
QTimer *m_timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(m_timer &QTimer::timeout(), this, &MainWindow::onTimer());
```

start the timer (perhaps in your `on_pushButton_clicked()` function):

```
m_timer.start(500);
```

On timer slot:

```
MainWindow::onTimer()
{
    ui->textBrowser->setText(m_in.readLine()); // read one line and (in is now member variable 'm_in'
    if (m_in.atEnd())
    {
        m_timer.stop(); // stop the timer we have reached the end.
        // Close the io stream etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to access the data in real time i.e. inspite of printing the data to a text file and then displaying it , I would like to get the data directly to the text edit. Not again from the text file. @code_fodder

Comment: @AkhilChandraMaganti I am not quite sure I understand you. Your data comes from a file, right? and you want to display this in your text edit? this line displays data into your text edit: `ui->textBrowser->setText(m_in.readLine());`, I don't quite see what you mean...

Comment: if you read my description I mentioned that i want the data in real time. if I take the data from a text file it is no more real-time. What I mentioned above is that, i tried using a text file and it worked out well. Now I want to use directly i.e. previously, I used to get the data into my linux terminal, now I want this data to be displayed into a textEdit/Label/ any other UI. Excuse me if I am not yet clear, I am clear though. In context of DDS I expect that you can understand (from my tags) that I receive the data from a remote terminal. If not no issues, doesn't matterabvcode

Comment: @AkhilChandraMaganti So you want to wait for incoming messages and then print them to screen as they arrive? Is there an event that occurs when a DDS message arrives? or do you have to keep polling the status? What you can do is, whenever a message arrives emit a signal to a "writer" object. The writer object will be responsible for writing the messages as they come in - detaching your read code from your write code.

Comment: @AkhilChandraMaganti Ideally your reader would be in a different thread to your writer; especially if it has to poll. If you can provide some further details as to how you detect incoming data I can produce an example. Feel free to add this to your question...